# html datalist not showing options in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, html-datalist

I make a server request to get streetnames and they should show up as datalist options....but in google chrome they didn't.
In Firefox and IE it pops up with the correct requested street names. Here is some Code:

the HTML:

```
      <li>
                <label>Straße <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="input_strasse" type="text" value ="Strasse" autocomplete="off" list="input_strasse_datalist" class="field-long" placeholder="Straße" />
                <datalist id="input_strasse_datalist" ></datalist>
            </li>
```

JS:

```
  $(document).on("keyup", "#input_strasse", function () {

            var inputStr = $('#input_strasse').val();
            var charStr = inputStr.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputStr.substr(1);


            var UrlToWebservice = window.localStorage.getItem("url_to_webservice");
            console.log("buchstabensuppe: ", charStr)

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: UrlToWebservice + 'SP_SELECT_Strassen',
                data: { 'charStr': charStr },
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (response) {
                   
                  //  var strassen = new Array;


                    $(response).find('STRASSE').each(function () {


                        var strasse = $(this).find('NAME').text();

                        var plz = $(this).find('PLZ').find('plz').text();

                        var ort = $(this).find('PLZ').find('ORT').text();

                        var arstrasse = $(this).find('AR').first().text();
                        console.log("arstrasse ", arstrasse)

                        $("#input_strasse_datalist").append('<option data-ar = ' + arstrasse + ' value = "' + strasse + ' (' + plz + ', ' + ort + ')">' + strasse + ' (' + plz + ', ' + ort + ')</option>')
                        
                        $("#input_plz").val(plz)
                        $("#input_ort").val(ort)

                    })

                },

                error: function () {
                    window.location.hash = "httperror";
                }
            })



        })
```

I recognized that user-agent gives datalist display: none; if I gave the datalist display: block; but it looks like this:

[image]

So it is not inside the Dropdown and no option is selectable. It should look like this:
[image]

The really strange thing is, that it works perfectly on the local version of the app. Only when I run it at the server in the local chrome the strange behaviour appears. I'm really clueless. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work after updating chrome.

No problem anymore with Version 63.0.3239.84.